# Access violation in a delphi class

Tags: class, delphi, delphi-7, access-violation

I have a class like so:

```
Component = class(TObject)  
  Name: string;               
  CurState: word;             
  States: array of state;   
  constructor Create(nm: string);
  procedure AddState(ccl: bool; const InB: BufArr; const OutB: BufArr);
  function GetStateCount(): Integer;
  end;
```

`States` is an array of `state`, which is also a class declaration.

```
 State = class(TObject)    
  InBuf: BufArr;            
  OutBuf: BufArr;           
  Cycle: bool;       
  constructor Create(ccl: bool; const InB: BufArr; const OutB: BufArr);
  end;
```

Each `component` can hold more than one `state`, which is why I have an array of `state`.

The `GetStateCount()` function should return the number of states a component has.The implementation is as follows:

```
function Component.GetStateCount(): Integer;
begin
  result:=Length(States);
end;
```

However, when I call this function in another procedure, I get the following error:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out the cause of this. Will appreciate any help.

Okay, here is that part of the code where I'm calling the function:

```
for i:=0 to nc-1 do
begin
cycle:=false;
len:=cmp[i].GetStateCount;
for j:=0 to len-1 do
   if not cmp[i].States[j].Cycle or cycle then
     continue;
   cycle:=true;
   for k:= 0 to length(cmp[i].States[j].InBuf)-1 do
   begin
     m:=cmp[i].States[j].InBuf[k];
     if m>0 then
     graph[m-1,i]:= graph[m-1,i]+1;
   end;
  end;
```

Comment: Can you provide full *.pas code ?

Comment: That's not your real code. If you want help with a problem with your code,  post your actual code. Making it up as you go is useless; it can create new problems or hide the actual problem. What you've posted is in no way complete, and it can't be compiled and/or used for testing. Read [mcve] and [edit] your question if you want us to help.

Comment: @KenWhite this is not his complete project, indeed. But you have no reason to say the code is "not real", it most probably is.

Comment: That's part of my code. The main code is actually very long, which is why I put up the fragment I figured could be the cause of the error.

Comment: @Emeka: The error is not in the code of your `Component` class itself, as shown here.  The error is in the other procedure that is trying to call `GetStateCount()` on a `Component` object. *THAT* code has not been shown here, but it clearly has a logic bug that needs fixing.

Comment: @Emeka also in Delphi exception dialogs you can usually just press Ctrl+Ins or Ctrl+C to copy the very text, so would not have to mess with screenshot pictures.

Comment: You haven't initialized your array `cmp`. So `cmp[i]` is `nil` and that's causing the crash.

Comment: Make a MCVE or do some debugging.

Answer (score 5):

Your `States` member is at offset `$00000000C` within the `Component` class, so a `Read of address 0000000C` error means the `States` member is being accessed from a nil `Component` pointer.  `$00455F54` is the memory address of the code that is calling `GetStateCount()`.  Use the debugger to jump to that memory address (if it hasn't already taken you there automatically when the error occurred) and figure out why that code is accessing a nil pointer.

---

**Update**: Based on the code snippet you have added, the problem is caused by `cmp[i]` being nil.  Look at the code that allocates and fills `cmp`, as it is not filling it in correctly.  My guess is that you are probably allocating `cmp` itself but forgetting to copy any `Component` object pointers into it, eg:

```
for I := 0 to nc-1 do
  cmp[i] := Component.Create; // <-- HERE!
```

Comment: See Ken's comments to my answer. Until the topicstarter would give him the TOTAL sources to his project he does not want this question to be answered

Comment: @Arioch'The: That does not warrant a downvote on a legit answer. And it is not Ken's decision whether answers are allowed to be posted or not. If Ken wants people to ignore this question, he can post a close vote (which no one here seems to have done yet). It is pretty easy to figure out from the OP's info what happened (a nil pointer is accessed). If the OP wants to figure out why there is a nil pointer being accessed, then the OP can update this question to show the calling code, or post a new question.

Comment: BTW, why it is +12 not +8 ? what is at offset +0, pointer to VMT ?

Comment: well, you can see, you would not have to convince ME in that, I more or less think similar :-)  And realsitically speaking, the dummy totally lost would anyway not be able to make a "minimal" example, as he would not be able to detect which code is irrelevant and can be thrown away :-)

Comment: `If the OP wants to figure out why there is a nil pointer being accessed, then the OP can update this question to show the calling code` - actually not, I think THAT would exactly constitute another (while related) question, not warping the existing question.

Comment: Nice of both you and @Arioch'The to assume I voted (either way) on anything but the original question. I'm certanily free to express an opinion (which I did on the other answer) about whether the question should have been answered in its current state or not. And if I *did* choose to downvote, it would be my vote to cast, and my decision how to cast it, as long as it wasn't serial voting. But thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite well, when there is the only spoken out "dissent" and at the same time there comes downvote that is the typical pattern "downvote with explanation" so that assumption was reasonable, while of course it could not be proven...  And anyway, there was not given any other reasons for downvoting, so I would still think the reasons voiced by you are behind it (regardless who did it), just for the lack of ANY other explanations.

Comment: @Arioch'The: That's the strangest way anyone has ever said to me *Sorry, Ken, for falsely assuming that you did something, publicly accusing you of it, and then falsely reporting you to someone else on a public site accusing you of the same wrong thing. I sincerely apologize.* Must be a cultural or language thing. We say it differently here.

Answer (score 1):

`Read of address 0000000xx` - note the referenced address is ALMOST zero but is SLIGHTLY above it - suggests that you did not created object when you try to access its internal fields ( within the call to that function ).

To test that hypothesis rewrite your function in that "defensive programming" way:

```
function Component.GetStateCount(): Integer;
begin
  if nil = Self then 
     raise Exception.Create ('I forgot to create the object!');

  result := Length( Self.States );
end;
```

If that customized exception is thrown - then it is it and you should debug why you did not created the component.

Field variables of your components objects are being offset from the value of `Self` pointer. And for Win32 programs they would typically be `memory-aligned` to 4-bytes (32 bits) boundaries.

Thus we would have

- Self + 0 ==> pointer to the VMT (Virtual Methods Table)
- Self + 4 ==> `Component.Name` // pointer to `TStringRec`
- Self + 8 ==> `Component.CurState` // two bytes used, two bytes "padded"
- Self + 12 ==> `Component.States` // pointer to dyn-array frame

hexadecimal 0000000C is exactly 12 which is (0 + 12) when `(Self=nil)`.

[Internal Data Formats (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_%28Delphi%29)

Note: in Delphi 7 some formats were different, for example Long Strings did not have the CodePage field.

---

In the code to the question `cmp[i]` sometimes is `nil` - and you would have to determine if that is valid situation or not.

If it is valid you have to check for it inside the loop.

```
for i:=0 to nc-1 do
begin
  if nil = cmp[I] then continue;
  cycle:=false;
  ...
```

If there should be no `nil` elements in the array you would have to determine how that could happen.

```
for i:=0 to nc-1 do
begin
  if nil = cmp[i] then raise Exception.Create(....);
  cycle:=false;
  ...
```

However I believe that is the point of a separate research (and maybe question). Here you asked why there was AV in the specific function and I think you have to check the `Self is nil` hypothesis as the direct cause.

Also - the repeating use of `cmp[i]` in the loop body does not look nice for me.
I suggest you to cache the value into a local variable you would create for exactly that.

```
for i:=0 to nc-1 do
begin
  curr_cmp := cmp[i];
  if nil = curr_cmp then raise Exception.Create(....);
  cycle := false;
  len := curr_cmp.GetStateCount;
  for j:=0 to len-1 do
     if not curr_cmp.States[j].Cycle or cycle then
      ...
```

It would letter make editing and understanding the code easier. If tomorrow you would move that code into a separate procedure or would decide to obtain the object from different source than `cmp[i]` you would only need to change ONE single line, instead of searching for al the `cmp[i]` occurences risking to lost one or two. I remember once I had to change the index variable from the straightforward loop to a way more complex indirect pattern, actually I had to start using TWO index variables, and then lazy copy-pasting `cmp[i]` bit me pretty nasty...

And as a bonus maybe that would also make code slightly faster.

Comment: Attempting to answer this question without any actual code in the OP does not benefit this user or any future readers here, and it removes any incentive for the OP to edit the question to provide the actual code.

Comment: `without any actual code in the OP` - most probably is delusion and wishful thinking. There is no reason to thing the code is not real.

Comment: The code will not compile, there's no information about the constructor, and there are typographic errors. It's not real code, and it's certainly not an MCVE.

Comment: `any future readers` definitely is a delusion and wishful thinking. This answer helps any future reader to detect probable Self=nil dereference by error message and then to test for it.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] clearly says that questions asking for debugging help need to include the actual code in the question. That's not the actual code. Not going to debate it with you anyway; my opinion clearly doesn't agree with yours. If you're so certain that it's a nil pointer question, vote to close it as a duplicate of the many other similar questions.

Comment: @KenWhite: feel free to submit your own vote to close the question, if you want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "VMT Table" is funny :-D